# How to create backpressure mitigation using rabbitmq as buffer in spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, spring-integration-amqp

I have an api which is running on *http://localhost:9999/greet/v3/api* (**API A**) which responds to requests with 2 seconds delay (simulated). And I have created following integration flow to proxy all requests to aforementioned api.

How to mitigate backpressure to **API A**?

Followings are what I have done so far:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpProxyFlowPin2(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
    return IntegrationFlow
            .from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/gw2")
                    .requestChannel(Amqp.channel(connectionFactory).queueName("request").getObject())
                    .replyChannel(Amqp.channel(connectionFactory).queueName("response").getObject())
                    .mappedRequestHeaders("activityid")
                    .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.GET)))
            .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9999/greet/v3/api").httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).charset("utf-8")
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(Amqp.channel(connectionFactory).queueName("response2").getObject())
            .get();
}
```

When I test the proxy api, I am receiving following error:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1777) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1723) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1593) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1570) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1561) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.lambda$executeListener$8(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1484) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$0(Observation.java:493) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.4.jar:1.11.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.4.jar:1.11.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:492) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.4.jar:1.11.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1484) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:994) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:941) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1323) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1225) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for amqp-channel 'application.response2.channel'.
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:306) ~[spring-integration-amqp-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:294) ~[spring-integration-amqp-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you are trying to achieve with all those AMQP-based channels in between. So, probably you can elaborate what is going on and why.

Regarding the error:

```
Dispatcher has no subscribers for amqp-channel 'application.response2.channel'.
```

That just means that your `.channel(Amqp.channel(connectionFactory).queueName("response2").getObject())` does not have a subscriber to consume messages from it. For your current configuration it would be just enough to have a `bridge()` in the end of flow - and consumed message from that AMQP channel is going to be returned as a reply to the `WebFlux.inboundGateway()` in the beginning.

You don't need a `replyChannel()` configuration on that gateway, though. It makes sense only in scenarios where we need to publish a reply to several consumers. You might need to use a `.enrichHeaders(HeaderEnricherSpec::headerChannelsToString)` before that `.channel(Amqp.channel())` to serialize a `TemporaryReplyChannel` into its string representation to be able to transfer this info over RabbitMQ. Otherwise you'll fail with no `replyChannel` header when we apply the mentioned `bridge()`.

Either way I'm curious what you really try to do and what is that `to mitigate backpressure` as a task?